# How to make top and left border of a div slanted

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

```css
.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin:auto;
}
.section1{
  background: #541A81;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
.content{
  background:#ffffff;
  /* clip-path: polygon(0 90px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); */
  border: 7px dashed #FFFD54;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 168px 60px 92px;
  transform: skew(10deg, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ad hic distinctio laboriosam iste neque quibusdam, adipisci sed magni explicabo nemo delectus nesciunt numquam non ducimus enim voluptatem ipsam! Esse!
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus dolorum unde debitis quos velit repudiandae. Explicabo, veniam, totam? Consectetur eum ab veniam, consequatur nemo, beatae soluta blanditiis quas quos dicta.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried skewing it, but it seems to be skewing the whole axis, I have also tried the `clip-path` approach (code is commented there), however, this clip method is also removing the border as well.

Comment: Hello dear, I think the best way to creat this type of card is to use **HTML CANVAS**: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp)

Comment: i will be adding some content there later. on that white box. so not sure if canvas could be the right options.

Comment: I found stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082308/irregular-div-shape-distort-one-corner-only) recently that might help point you in the right direction. Someone else referred to it as `deforming an HTML element using CSS` which a google search presents a bunch of good results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't recommend this, however you theoretically *could* achieve something similar using pseudo elements - albeit it could get a bit messy with the [perspective css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) to skew in 3D.

Using pseudo elements, you could stop the actual text becoming skewed as you only apply these to the pseudo elements rather than the whole element.

```css
body {
  background: #541A81;
}

.wrap,
.light {
  perspective: 300px;
}

.light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.light:before,
.light:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.light:after {
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: 90%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transform: rotateY(10deg) rotate(5deg);
  z-index: -5;
}

.light:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 55px);
  background: white;
  border: 7px dashed #FFFD54;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotateY(-5deg) rotateX(2deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="light">
    hello! This text won't be skewed or messed up.
  </div>
</div>
```